# Why does my Adobe Reader render PDFs so poorly?

Tags: pdf, fonts, adobe-reader, pdf-reader, embedded-fonts

I'm using Adobe Reader 9.4.3 on Windows 7.  Everything is pretty much as is out of the box. I have not done anything special with fonts or smoothing. In Linux and even Windows/Chrome things look like this:

[image]

In Adobe/Windows they look like this:

[image]

Comment: you can give another pdf reader like foxit reader, sumatra a try. They are better and faster than abode for reading purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should [update](http://get.adobe.com/reader/) to the current version of adobe reader for windows 7, which is version 10.1.2.

Comment: A lot of my readers would be using V9.  I would like to know how to fix things if they experience the same issue for space.  It is still a relatively recent piece of software I don't see why it should have problems rendering a plain vanilla PDF.

Comment: if you need to use version 9, then update to version 9.5 through the link provided in my initial post. read [this](http://grok.lsu.edu/mobile/article.aspx?articleid=9248) and report back if the issue persists.

Comment: It was a font smoothing issue.  Why is this turned off by default very strange

Comment: it isn't turned off by default. per the article i linked to, adobe reader 9 detects the type of monitor being utilized and chooses the 'best' text smoothing option; i suppose 'best' is an arbitrary specification though.

Answer (score 16):

Go to Edit>Preferences>Page Display>Rendering>, from the smooth text drop-down option choose "For laptop/LCD screens". Your problem must be solved.

Comment: Why is this still not the default setting in 2018?!

Answer (score 3):

Font smoothing must be off.
Goto Edit > Prefrences > Smooth Text > Select a smoothing method

Just did it, my works fine now

Answer (score 0):

I observed a similar problem in rendering when opening a second pdf document while the first showed sharp fonts. Try to turn off 'Use 2D graphics acceleration on Edit>Page Display>Rendering. For me it worked.